# In Android 11 it is possible to open file manager with a folder?

Tags: android, kotlin

So,

I would like to open the file manager from my application, with my application private storage, to show all the files.

I tried to open with Action_VIEW,ACTION_GET_CONTENT
And I also tried set intent type to */*,application/*

The result is the android offer a lot off application but not the file exporer, or I just simple get error, because there is no application to the action.

I use a Samsung tablet, with default file explorer

[Updated]

```
val uri = Uri.parse(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)?.path)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.setDataAndType(uri,"resource/folder")
            try {
                startActivity(intent)
            }catch (e: Exception){
                throw e
            }

Open document tree intent
    fun createDocumentTreeIntent(fileName: String, extension: String): Intent {
        return Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

            type = if (extension == "jpeg" || extension == "jpg" || extension == "png")
                "image/${extension}"
            else
                "application/${extension}"

            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "${fileName}.${extension}")
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no documented and supported way to open a "file manager" on a directory.

Also, few apps will have access to the directory that you seek, on Android 11 and higher. Some will today courtesy of `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`, but that will no longer be an option in the coming months. Some might still have access after that, via `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or manufacturer-granted permissions.

Comment: Tanks, I' am sad, with andoird 11+ there is a lot restriction, which makes developers work hard. 

And is there a way, to show my application files? Because I think, it is hard to find where is the application private download folder, for the users. My temporary solution is that, I show my files in a fragment which are in the private storage, and the user can open it from my application, but i dont think it is right solution.

Comment: "it is hard to find where is the application private download folder, for the users" -- use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) and let the users decide where to place the content on their device or in their cloud storage providers.

Comment: `In Android 11 it is possible to open file manager with a folder?` Yes that is possible using something like  `.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, previousUri)`. Where previousUri points to a file you selected earlier. But.. never for getExternalFilesDir() on Android 11.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I implemented the document tree, and it works perfectly, but what I mistake, because if there is already a file with the same name, the document tree automatic add a string to the end of the file, but with this, the file is corrupted, because the modified file will be something this: filename.jpg(1) and not filename(1).jpg. Anybody know what I have donr wrong?

Comment: @Andreas1234 If you think you found the solution and it is working, then can you post it as a answer so that others will be seeing it

Comment: @S A R Unfortunatelly I have not find the sulution yet. So I just created a new fregment, where I listed out the files inside my private storage. I had to do it so that users could delete these files.